# pausing message sending & receiving from a java web app

Tags: java, multithreading, message, netty

need help in designing a web app that can send and receive messages. it must have a pause functionality. i am having trouble in thinking how can i pause the sending and receiving (threads scare me T_T).
the receiving end are clients/servers (using netty)

any suggestions are more than welcome. thanks!!

Comment: Whats the exact aim to pause sending and receiving? why you need such functionality? will you please elaborate?

Comment: I think we need some more context about what the web app is doing. It needs to communicate with a back-end using a message protocol... synchronous or asynchronous flows? Or is this two web clients communicating with each other (e.g. a chat application)?

Comment: sorry guys.. the web app is for sending receiving iso8583 messages.. so pausing simulates (or forces) the timeout.. they also wanted to run it in a given amount of time.. i figured if i know how to pause, i will have an idea on how to send/receive messages in a given amount of time.. the web app can be run by multiple users at the same time. every user can run simultaneous sending/receiving..

i really do not have a concrete idea yet on the design but someone suggested to use JMS..

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Greg/Harry that more information is needed, but let me state that threads got a lot less scary in Java 5 and 6 with the introduction of **java.util.concurrent**, which is a higher level of abstraction that deals with many real-world threading situations out out the box.  If I understand what you want to do correctly, please start out by looking at [BlockingQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html).

If you simply want a send/receive mechanism that can be paused, though, set up a [finite state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) that has states for INIT, ROUTE, and PAUSE.  INIT is for startup before it's ready to do it's job, ROUTE is for when it's waiting for messages to receive to send out, and PAUSE is for when it receives a PAUSE command, and it sits and waits for a RESUME command.

You can run this process (and any others) in a separate thread inside your web app using [java.util.concurrent.Executor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html).